# How to remove or change small margins on firefox extension popup?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, kango-framework

I'm building an extension with Kango. In Chrome everything works fine and there are no margins or borders, but in Firefox I have these margins. How can I fix this?

[image: Borders]

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: You have to load CSS into the browser that affects just your panel.

Comment: @Noitidart  I already have css that affects just on my panel. But how to inspect dom on my panel? or how to remove this borders? This is not clear for me

Comment: @UlyanichVyacheslav you need to download addon DOMInspector - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/ && download addon Element Inspector - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-inspector/ && then get your panel to open, then shift+right click on it, and it will open in the DOM Inspector :)

Comment: @Noitidart I did so, but when I'm trying to inspect dom, popup is closing and I dont' see, what I should to remove or something else. Do you know any ways how can I hold popup opened?